# Should commit replace directive if it's pointing to a local module?

Tags: go, module

As far as I understand, `replace` directive is useful to test *published* 3rd party packages. What if I'm using it to point to a local module just so `Go` is aware of its location, is it safe to commit it to the repo? What are the pitfalls in doing so? I'm using `v1.18.x`.

**UPDATE**

Here's how my project looks

```
app/
|---lambdaFuncOne/
|   |---go.mod
|---lambdaFuncTwo/
|   |---go.mod
|---pkg/
|   |---customOne/
|   |   |---go.mod
|---go.work
```

`pkg/customOne` is used in both `lambdaFuncOne` and `lambdaFuncTwo`, so their `go.mod` file has this

```
replace github.com/user/proj/app/pkg/customOne => ../pkg/customOne
```

It's a relative path so I guess it's always valid?

`go.work` has this

```
go 1.18

use (
   ./lambdaFuncOne
   ./lambdaFuncTwo
   ./pkg/customOne 
)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [workspace](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces); this supports "writing code in multiple modules at the same time". The issue with committing a `go.mod` that contains a `replace` directive is that if someone else gets the module the replace directive might not be valid in their environment. It would help if you provided an example because [`replace`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) can be used in a few different was; I'm guessing that you are using it with a local path.

Comment: @Brits What do you mean by `might not be valid`? I updated my question btw. Thanks!

Edit: I am in fact using workspace. I'm not sure why I have to use replace directive in this case. If I don't, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should not need to use `replace` in`go.mod` with that structure. Check the `module`  definitions in your `go.mod` files. Perhaps remove  the `replace` and tell us what the resulting error is. By "Might not be valid" I mean that the files might not be in the specified location on another users drive.

Comment: @Brits I am actually oversimplifying my code structure. Truth is the `app` directory exists inside a repo -- a monorepo and I have no control over it. So If I remove the replace directive, it'll attempt to download `pkg/customOne` package which will fail of course. 

If I disallow restructuring `app`, will `../pkg/customOne` work without issues?

Answer (score 3):

In brief you can commit the `replace` as long as you also commit the things it is redirecting to.  We often do this to work on a package locally before pushing to github.  You might also use it if you have modified an open source package but don't want to share the changes.

Originally, a common use for replace was for temporarily testing or trying an alternative version of a package. But many people were accidentally committing `go.mod` with the temporary `replace` clause so that is why Go 1.18 introduced the workspace file.

So use `workspace` for local temporary experiments. Use `replace` for (semi)permanent redirection. Always commit your go.mod file but never commit the workspace file.

This is my understanding. I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong.